ZAP warnings solving
I have been trying to solve some warnings from ZAP ( Medium ) but got no luck.I'm trying to run a React app ( currently testing enviroment) and despite setting CORS, Headers, and CSP on my backend ( express ) , it looks like for some URLs that i didn't personally make (/static,/ws,/sitemap.xml I guess they are from React ) the rules wont apply
below is the backend code that works for most of my endpoints, but not for the above mentioned
app.use(helmet());

// Define the CORS middleware function
const allowCors = (req, res, next) => {
    const allowedOrigin = 'http://localhost:3000'; // Specify the allowed origin
    const origin = req.headers.origin;
    console.log('Origin:', req.headers.origin); // Log the origin value

    if (req.headers.origin === allowedOrigin || origin === 'http://localhost:5000/') {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
        res.setHeader('Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy', 'cross-origin'); 

    }

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');

    // Set Content-Security-Policy header with additional directives
    const cspHeader = `
        default-src 'self';
        form-action 'self'; 
        frame-ancestors 'self'; 
    `.replace(/\n\s+/g, ' '); // Remove newlines and extra spaces from the header value

    res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', cspHeader);
// Add anti-clickjacking header
res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN');
 console.log(res.headers)
    next();
};
const limiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
    max: 100 // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
});
app.use(allowCors);
// Apply CORS middleware for a specific endpoint
 
app.use(limiter);

// Apply Helmet middleware for security headers
 

// Apply CSP configuration
 

app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
        defaultSrc: ["'self'","localhost:5000/",'"localhost:3000/'],
        scriptSrc: ["'self'", "localhost:5000/", "https://js.stripe.com/"],
        styleSrc: ["'self'", "https://fonts.googleapis.com"],
        imgSrc: ["'self'", "http://localhost:5000/", "http://localhost:3000/", "data:"], // Add 'self' to imgSrc directive
        fontSrc: ["'self'", "https://fonts.googleapis.com"], // Add 'self' to fontSrc directive
        formAction: ["'self'"], // Define form-action directive to allow forms to submit to the same origin
        frameAncestors: ["'self'"], // Define frame-ancestors directive to restrict embedding to the same origin
     
    },
     
}));

